Add an array of objects as a parameter to a constructor
I am working on a Java quiz application. In this I want the four answer options to be as an array instead of coding it is as Option 1,2,..4. How do I add an array of objects to the constructor?
I am pasting my code here:

POJO Class
package com.param;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String opt1;
    private String opt2;
    private String opt3;
    private String opt4;
    private String answer;

    public Question(int id, String question, String opt1, String opt2,String opt3, String opt4, String answer) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.opt1 = opt1;
        this.opt2 = opt2;
        this.opt3 = opt3;
        this.opt4 = opt4;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getOpt1() {
        return opt1;
    }
    public void setOpt1(String opt1) {
        this.opt1 = opt1;
    }
    public String getOpt2() {
        return opt2;
    }
    public void setOpt2(String opt2) {
        this.opt2 = opt2;
    }
    public String getOpt3() {
        return opt3;
    }
    public void setOpt3(String opt3) {
        this.opt3 = opt3;
    }
    public String getOpt4() {
        return opt4;
    }
    public void setOpt4(String opt4) {
        this.opt4 = opt4;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [id=" + id + ", question=" + question + ", opt1=" + opt1 + ", opt2=" + opt2 + ", opt3=" + opt3
                + ", opt4=" + opt4 + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
    }
}


Question Service class
package com.param;

public class QuestionService {
    Question[] questions = new Question[4];

    public QuestionService() {
        questions[0] = new Question(1,"Value of pie","3.12","3.01", "3.14", "3.11", "3.14");
        questions[1] = new Question(2,"Your age", "24","54", "35", "25", "25");
        questions[2] = new Question(3,"This year", "1898","2034", "2024", "1999", "2024");
        questions[3] = new Question(4,"Days in jan", "31","30", "34", "11", "31");
    }

    public void playQuiz() {
        System.out.println("The quiz begins");
        for(Question q: questions) {
            //System.out.println(q.getId()+"\t");
            System.out.println(q.getId() + "." + q.getQuestion()+"\n");
            System.out.println(q.getOpt1()+"\n");
            System.out.println(q.getOpt2()+"\n");
            System.out.println(q.getOpt3()+"\n");
            System.out.println(q.getOpt4()+"\n");
        }
    }
}



In the Question service class, instead of giving each individual option as a parameter, how can I give the array of that object?

There are couple of ways.

Using arrays (String[]) as an input. In such case, the Question class would look like this:
public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String[] options;
    private String answer;

    public Question(int id, String question, String[] options, String answer) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.options = options; // <-- replacing all options
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    // other methods are omitted.

    public String[] getOptions() {  
       return options; // <-- getting all options
    }
}

And then using this constructor in the QuestionService class, would look like this:
public class QuestionService {
    public QuestionService() {
        questions[0] = new Question(1, "Value of pie", new String[]{"3.12", "3.01", "3.14", "3.11"}, "3.14"); // <-- Notice using new String[] {...} instead of passing values directly
        // same goes to other questions
    }
    // other code is omitted
}


Using varargs (String...) as an input.
For more info, please refer to varargs official documentation
public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String[] options;
    private String answer;

    public Question(int id, String question, String answer, String... options) { // <-- varargs must be the last argument. So, switching the answer and options are a must.
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.options = options; // <-- replacing all options (varargs is an array)
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    // other methods are omitted.

    public String[] getOptions() {  
       return options;
    }
}

And then using this constructor in the QuestionService class, would look like this:
public class QuestionService {
    public QuestionService() {
        questions[0] = new Question(1, "Value of pie", "3.14", "3.12", "3.01", "3.14", "3.11"); // <-- Notice that all values goes into the array without using new String[] {...}
        // same goes to other questions
    }
    // other code is omitted
}



A complete example using arrays:
Note: setters methods in Question are removed as the internal values of a question should not be modified after creation.

Question class:
package com.param;

public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String[] options;
    private String answer;

    public Question(int id, String question, String[] options, String answer) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.options = options;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public String[] getOptions() {
        return options;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [id=" + id + ", question=" + question + ", options=" + options + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
    }
}


QuestionService class:
package com.param;

public class QuestionService {
    Question[] questions = new Question[4];

    public QuestionService() {
        questions[0] = new Question(1, "Value of pie", new String[]{"3.12", "3.01", "3.14", "3.11"}, "3.14");
        questions[1] = new Question(2, "Your age", new String[]{"24", "54", "35", "25"}, "25");
        questions[2] = new Question(3, "This year", new String[]{"1898", "2034", "2024", "1999"}, "2024");
        questions[3] = new Question(4, "Days in jan", new String[]{"31", "30", "34", "11"}, "31");
    }

    public void playQuiz() {
        System.out.println("The quiz begins");
        for (Question q : questions) {
            //System.out.println(q.getId()+"\t");
            System.out.println(q.getId() + "." + q.getQuestion() + "\n");
            // Using for-loop to iterate over available options
            for (String option : q.getOptions()) {
                System.out.println(option + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}




Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It really helped the problem. Can you please brief me on why you removed the setters in the POJO class? For my understanding

Also I want to create an inner loop in the playQuiz method to display the options in the loop itself. How do i do that? The getters are different for all the options right?

@ParameshAthreya, I removed the setters cause the Question class is immutable. Meaning, that during the life cycle of the program, its state cannot be changed. In your program, the question with its answer and options cannot change. So, once it is created, none of its properties can be changed. I suggest you read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

@ParameshAthreya, I updated the playQuiz method to use for-loop to iterate over the options and print them. Also, note the changes in the Question class (used getOptions and removed getOpt1, getOpt2, etc since they are not used any more).

If Question is immutable and meant primarily to communicate data transparently, we can make it a record, becoming even shorter: public record Question (     int id, String question, String[] options, String answer ) {}

In Java, an array is a reference type, a type of Object. An array literal can be specified by invoking the constructor for each element:
class Foo {
   private int fooI;
   private double fooD;
   private String fooS;

   public Foo (int i, double d, String S) { ... }
   ...
   Foo [] myFoo =  new Foo [] {new Foo (1,2.3,"Bar")
      , new Foo (100,18.75212,"Bin"), new Foo (-24,-49.49,"Bat")};
   ...
}

You can specify an array literal in an argument list:
   public static void FooThis (Foo[] fooArr) { ... }
...
   fooThis ( new Foo [] {new Foo (1,2.3,"Bar")
      , new Foo (100,18.75212,"Bin"), new Foo (-24,-49.49,"Bat")};

So, start by  modifying your Question class to use an array for options:
public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String [] option;   // no need to specify size here
    private String answer;
    
    public Question(int id, String question, String[] options, String answer) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.option = options;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getOption (int index) {
       return option [index];
    }

    public void setOption (int index, String option) {
        this.option [index] = option;
    }

You can use the toString [Object[] method from the Arrays API:
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [id=" + id + ", question=" + question + ",
            Options:" + Arrays.toString [option] + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
    }

But, the output might look neater if you have each option on its own line.
Now, here is how you can use array literals. In this example, you will have array literals within array literals:
public class QuestionService {
    Question[] questions ;

    public QuestionService() {
       questions = new Question [] {
           new  Question (1,"Value of ",
                        new String []{"3.12","3.01", "3.14", "3.11"}
                       ,"3.14)
         , new Question (2,"Your age",
                       new String [] {"24","54","35","25","72","107"}
                      ,"25")      
          // and so on
           };

You can use nested loops: Outer loop for the question, and an inner loop for each option.
Comments:

Consider not having setter methods. Will a user of the Question class have a need to change the question, options, or answer after the Question Object is constructed?

This approach is more flexible.

It allows one quiz to have a different number of questions than another quiz.
It allows one question to have different number of options than another question.  I tried to show that by adding some ages to the 2nd question. This allows a quiz to have a mixture of multiple choice with true / false questions.


I didn't include code to guard against the possibility of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You might want to add that to your code. For example, if a Question has 5 options, instead of having the program abort,  you might want to control what happens if a user tries to answer with option 7 or negative 1.


